# FFMPEG: Sync issue between mp3 and mp4 converted from the same input webm file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, mp3, codec

#### Using this command to create 2 files :

`ffmpeg -y -i input.webm -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -strict -2 -f mp4 rec_50ae1a2a3da64cf1a5f46c53de757d6e-1692704540213.mp4 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -f mp3 rec_50ae1a2a3da64cf1a5f46c53de757d6e-1692704540213.mp3`

- rec_50ae1a2a3da64cf1a5f46c53de757d6e-1692704540213.mp4
- rec_50ae1a2a3da64cf1a5f46c53de757d6e-1692704540213.mp3

the mp3 file is sent to a third party along with speaker labels which is then used to generate a transcript that gets rendered along with the mp4 file in a UI.

#### Observation:

- there is a sync delay between the transcript and the mp4, which increases from 0 sec delay at the starting of the video and gradually increase with time (video goes slower)
- the duration of the mp4 is greater than that of the mp3
- even after ensuring that the bitrate of the mp4's audio and mp3 audio is same sync issue is observed
- no delay between the mp4's audio and the mp3 file
- no sync issue between the transcript and the mp3 files.
- issue only occurs when mp4 is compared to the transcript.

```
mediainfo rec_50ae1a2a3da64cf1a5f46c53de757d6e-1692704540213.mp4
General
Complete name                            : rec_50ae1a2a3da64cf1a5f46c53de757d6e-1692704540213.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 148 MiB
Duration                                 : 23 min 57 s
Overall bit rate                         : 864 kb/s
Frame rate                               : 17.677 FPS
Writing application                      : Lavf59.27.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Constrained Baseline@L4.2
Format settings                          : 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, Reference frames        : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 23 min 57 s
Source duration                          : 23 min 55 s
Bit rate                                 : 734 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 960 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 17.677 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 1.176 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 62.500 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.034
Stream size                              : 126 MiB (85%)
Source stream size                       : 126 MiB (85%)
Language                                 : English
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Format settings                          : Joint stereo / MS Stereo
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-6B
Duration                                 : 23 min 57 s
Source duration                          : 23 min 57 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 21.8 MiB (15%)
Source stream size                       : 21.8 MiB (15%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.100
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```

```
mediainfo rec_50ae1a2a3da64cf1a5f46c53de757d6e-1692704540213.mp3
General
Complete name                            : rec_50ae1a2a3da64cf1a5f46c53de757d6e-1692704540213.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 22.3 MiB
Duration                                 : 24 min 20 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 128 kb/s
Writing library                          : LAME3.100

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Format settings                          : Joint stereo / MS Stereo
Duration                                 : 24 min 20 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 41.667 FPS (1152 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 22.3 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.100
```

how do I fix this ?